# What is the meaning of this java code format

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Generics - What is this syntax for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238150/java-generics-what-is-this-syntax-for)
>   [In Java What is the < > notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400719/in-java-what-is-the-notation)

```java
sBooksProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Could anyone explain to me the meaning of this part of of above code:

```java
new HashMap<String, String>()
```

I'm a newbie for Java and the `<Sting, String>` part is confusing me.

Comment: `HashMap<String, String>()` it says that HashMap key and value will be of `String` type

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati LMGTFY links are banned for a good reason.

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh I don't know them either. Sorry.

Comment: Upvoted. If you don't know the keyword 'generic' it's damn hard to search for it. This is a newbie question, not a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply-

```
Map< key, value > map = new HashMap< key, value >();
```

example would be

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("str","abcd");
map.put("str1","dcba");
```

Now getting them simply

```
map.get("str");  // abcd
map.get("str1"); // dcba
```